# Correct Model structure for django app?

Tags: python, django

I have a blog app that consists of 3 models: `department, author, post`

I am having trouble structuring the models correctly and creating the corresponding forms

`models.py`

```
    from django.db import models

    class Department(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        posts = models.ForeignKey('Post')
        authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

    class Author(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        post = models.ForeignKey('Post')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.last_name

    class Post(models.Model):
        title=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        post = models.TextField()
        creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

The idea is that a department can have many posts, but each post belongs to only one department. A department can also be made up of multiple authors and authors can be in multiple departments. Where I'm really having trouble is with the forms.

The relevant `urls.py` looks like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<department_id>\d+)/posts/$', views.posts, name='posts'),
url(r'^(?P<department_id>\d+)/add_post/$', views.add_post, name="add_post"),
```

So I can pull in all the posts by department. The goal of the form is for the department id to be recognized and added automatically to the post.

```
def add_post(request, department_id):
    department = Department.objects.get(pk=department_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_post_form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
        if new_post_form.is_valid():
            new_post = new_post_form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.department = department
            new_post.save()
            return redirect('posts', department_id=department_id)
```

Now I realize that the `Post model` does not have a department attribute, which is the error that I get, but I'm guessing that there's a way to make this happen, I just don't know what it is.

Thanks as always for your help. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the Post model does not have a department attribute should have given you the clue that your structure is wrong: it clearly needs one. The issue is that you have your ForeignKey the wrong way round: a FK is a one-to-many relationship, and lives on the "many" side, in your case Post, pointing to the "one", ie the Department.

Then your view code will work exactly as it is, and you can retrieve all posts for a department with `my_department.post_set.all()`.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate it. I'm still confused as to what type of attribute type department should have in the Post model though.

Comment: A ForeignKey. Just move it from Department to Post.